# How to run Java Program through shell_exec command in PHP?

Tags: java, php

I have a `PHP Project` with the name `itext`. Inside this folder I have  a `workspace` folder.
So the Path to the Java Class file is like this:

```
itext/workspace/sampleproject/checkFonts.java
```

I have an `index.php` file in  `itext` folder. How can I execute the `shell_exec` command in the index.php for the java file located in the above path?

**UPDATE:**

As per the answer I tried out stuffs and executed the below code and it works but I am getting the below error:

```
$output = array();
exec('java workspace/itext/src/itext/CheckFonts 2>&1',$output);
print_r($output);
```

**Error:**

> Array ( [0] => Error: Could not find or load main class
>   workspace.itext.src.itext.CheckFonts )

Comment: This may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/3023715/1793718

Comment: Your error is related to the original question as is more a matter of your coding error. You should open a new question if you have a problem with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify any path relative to the file your code is running from. So from your `index.php` the path would be `workspace/sampleproject`

If you want to use the full explicit directory you can use `realpath()` function:

`realpath('workspace/sampleproject');`

Here's a guide to running Java at the command line for windows environment: http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html

Your example code might be:

```
$javaPath = realpath('workspace/sampleproject');
$output = shell_exec('C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe '
                     . $javaPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'checkFonts');`
```

Comment: How does that help me in running a java class from shell_exec command?!!

Comment: `exec [path to java executable/]java [path to java file]checkFonts` - where [] marks optional?

Comment: I have a problem. I changed the question.check it

Comment: I want to know how its run that is first it should be getting compliled and then executed

Comment: I edited my answer with link showing how to complile and run. Does that answer your Q?

Comment: Give some example of using it with shell_exec

Comment: What is the path to your java executable file?

Comment: This is my path `workspace\itext\src\itext\CheckFonts.java`

Comment: No, where did you install the ORACLE java runtime environment. (e.g. C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath or /usr/bin/java)

Comment: Hi, pls check, this is where it is C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe

Comment: Shouldnt it end with `.java` like  DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'checkFonts.java' ?

Comment: Once you've compliled your java code, you get .class and .java files. Without any extension, it refers to the collective files as a single program

Comment: Plus one  for your support but still I am not able to run

Comment: hi..Check my updated question,I tried out that got that error, can u suggest something to solve that error?